# there is no row at position ''

Tags: c#

```cs
while (j<maxrow - 1)
{
    j++;
    if (txtfam2.Text == dt.Rows[j]["surname"].ToString())
    {
        txttel2.Enabled = btnup.Enabled = btnnext.Enabled = true;
        txtnme2.Text = dt.Rows[j]["name"].ToString();
        txttel2.Text = dt.Rows[j]["tel"].ToString();
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        txtnme2.Text = txttel2.Text = "";
        btnnext.Enabled = btnup.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

what am i doing wrong? I tried everything. I added data to my table but when I try to bring it up, it doesn't work.help?

`if (txtfam2.Text == dt.Rows[j]["surname"].ToString())`

Answer (score 1):

You're incrementing `j` in the beginning of the loop after the while loop checks the condition. move it to the bottom of the loop so it could be asserted before you're referencing the rows at the j index.

```
               while (j < maxrow - 1)
                {
                    if (txtfam2.Text == dt.Rows[j]["surname"].ToString())
                    {
                        txttel2.Enabled = btnup.Enabled = btnnext.Enabled = true;
                        txtnme2.Text = dt.Rows[j]["name"].ToString();
                        txttel2.Text = dt.Rows[j]["tel"].ToString();
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        txtnme2.Text = txttel2.Text = "";
                        btnnext.Enabled = btnup.Enabled = false;
                    }
                    j++;
                }
```